# R Pass formula to dataframe in a function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with column A.

I want to have a function like this:

```
myFunction <- function(df,term) {
  df = df[,term]
  return(df)
}
```

so I can do this:

```
myFunction(mydf,"sqrt('A')"))
```

or this:

```
myFunction(mydf,"log('A')"))
```

I tired modifying the function with the following but didn't work:

```
df = df[,I(term)]
df = df[,as.formula(term)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a `data.frame` or a `data.table` (they are different)? You can't pass a formula/expression to a data.frame like that.

Comment: @MrFlick it's a data.frame.

Comment: Please add to the question what you want the outcome to be. You've given us code that doesn't work and doesn't make sense and expect us to figure out your intentions from it. Please take the time to tell us more.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate `term` and add the results to your data.frame or are you trying to extra a column that already exists with the name contained within `term`?

Comment: Does this come closer to what you are trying to describe? `frm <- "sqrt(A)"; dplyr::mutate_(df, frm);` (notice the lack of single-quotes around the column name)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as arguments, which probably beats sending a string of the function:

```
myFunction <- function(df,term,fun) {
  vec = df[,term]
  fun(vec)
}

data(iris)

# answers
sum(iris$Sepal.Width)
mean(iris$Sepal.Width)

# use 'Sepal.Width' column instead of 'A'
myFunction(iris,'Sepal.Width',sum)
myFunction(iris,'Sepal.Width',mean)

# using a function string
myFunctionStr <- function(df,term,funstr) {
  vec = df[,term]
  eval(call(funstr,vec))
}

myFunctionStr(iris,'Sepal.Width','sum')
myFunctionStr(iris,'Sepal.Width','mean')
```

One way to evaluate a string as code is like this:

```
eval(parse(text = 'sqrt(16)'))
```

I would be really surprised if that was the best way to accomplish your task though.